# Last ID not showing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to grab the largest ID number from the database. The output should be 15 but it shows 1. My PHP script:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM employees";

$sql = $db->prepare($sql);

$lid = $sql->execute();
```

I am outputting it here:

```
<input type="number" name="id" value="<?php echo $lid; ?>" disabled>
```

I have also tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM employees ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

I tried the command on phpMyAdmin. It worked fine. The output was 15. So, I suspect that there are no problems in the query.

What is the problem, then?

Comment: You forgot to fetch the row with the result. The `1` (`true` really) that you have now just means that the query was executed succesfully.

Comment: Add this before execute  statement $lid = $sql->fetch();

Comment: Use `fetch_assoc()` or `fetch_object()` before executing your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [FETCH](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) i.e., `$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

So, You shall have something like

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM employees";
$sql = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

**Note :** Simply `$lid = $sql->execute();` means it will assign whether the query is executing or not.

As your query is executing it is returning true which is `1`

**Update :** If you are not binding any values you don't even need to prepare, you shall fetch it directly like Adelphia said

Comment: you're missing your `prepare()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM employees");
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

No need for prepared statements since it's a static query.